# Multiple if statements to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert this loop to a list comprehension but I'm stuck (A,B,C and D) are lists:

```
x = 0
for i in A:
  if i in B:
    if C[x] == D[x]:
       x = x + 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
[if i in A for i in B]
```

Not sure where to go from here.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `if i in B: if C[x] == D[x]` is the same as `if (i in B) and (C[x] == D[x])`.

Comment: You can simplify that if statement so that you don't need multiple conditionals. But I'm not sure how you plan to deal with `x` being required to access the elements of `C` and `D`... I don't suppose that's a typo and you meant `i`?

Comment: You aren't building a list, so a list comprehension isn't appropriate.

Comment: Your original loop doesn't seem to use `i`, is that intentional? Are `C`, `D` or `x` actually expressions that contain `i`?

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do? Because it looks pretty weird. If I read this correctly, `x` would end up the first index where `C` and `D` differ, but at most the number of common elements in `A` and `B`, is this what it's intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
sum([C[x] == D[x] for x in A if x in B])
```

This will implicitly convert `True`s to 1 and `False`s to 0.

Word of caution: You are trying to produce a single value out of this (aka *reduce*). List comprehensions are ideally for creating lists (*map*). Complex list comprehensions can be less readable.

I think this one maybe passes, but it's a little weird to do a sum over booleans.

---

Edit: As a comment pointed out, I assumed you actually meant to use the keys of `A` and `B` to index `C` and `D`, not the counter variable `x` in your original code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:-

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,1,6]
C = [7,8,9]
D = [7,4,1]
x = 0

[i for i in A if (i in B) and (C[x]==D[x]) ]
```

**Output**

```
[1]
```